# backbone.js how to: when an attribute is set, automatically update another

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

Folks, wondering about best practice and an API detail for the following
situation.

Let's say we have a model Selection:

```js
Selection = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    value : null,
    related: null,
    other: null,
    stuff: null
  }
}
```

If we change just 'value' without setting 'related' also, then we want
to set the 'related' to null---Sort of a cascading update.

There are other listeners that need to see the updated value of
'related' when 'value' is changed. So, we want to guarantee that
when any of those listeners are invoked, that 'related' is updated
accordingly.

So we could, perhaps, have the Selection model itself listen on
'change:value', and set 'related' if necessary. But does Backbone
guarantee that that listener will be called before any other listener of
'change:value'? Likewise, is it guaranteed that qualified events will
fire before generic events, so 'change:value' before 'change'?

Relying on the event system to do this seems fragile so we looked
for some hook. The closest thing we could find is _validate/validate
methods, where we could add to our Selection model something like:

```js
// Use _validate as a "before-set call" to set 'related' if necessary
_validate: function(attrs, options) {
  if (!_.has(attrs, 'related') && _.has(attrs, 'value') && 
      !_.isEqual(attrs.value, this.attributes.value)) {
    attrs.related = null;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Of course, this goes against the semantics implied by "validate".

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override [Model.set](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-41) and include your test.

Someting along those lines :

```
var Selection = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        value : null,
        related: null,
        other: null,
        stuff: null
    },

    set: function(key, val, options) {
        var attrs;

        //nothing to set
        if (key == null) return this;

        if (typeof key === 'object') {
           // setting a hash
            attrs = key;
            options = val;
        } else {
           // setting a key-value pair
            (attrs = {})[key] = val;
        }

        // set related values
        if (!_.has(attrs, 'related') && _.has(attrs, 'value') &&  
                  !_.isEqual(attrs.value, this.attributes.value)) {
            attrs.related = null;
        }

        // call the parent
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, options);
    }
});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/KSHwc/

Comment: We did consider this and thought that the code smell of repeating the key-val/hash-options handling logic at the top was a sign we were going down the wrong path.  But, you (and nEEbz) are right I think.  It is the cleanest way though it could be a lot cleaner it set() was re-factored a little so that you did not have to repeat that boilerplate every place you want to override set().  Thanks much.  We have our way forward!

Answer (score 0):

As Backbone.Model set method supports passing multiple attributes, I would suggest overriding it.

Something along the lines (Sorry for using CoffeeScript - as `super` is a bit straightforward here):

```
class myView extends Backbone.View
   set: (attributes, options) ->
       if attributes.value == "something"
             attributes.related = null
             #set all the cascade updates in the attributes object
       super(attributes,options)
```